# Connecting using shared access policy and key to IoT Hub using AMQP lite

Tags: azure, authentication, amqp, sasl, azure-iot-hub

Following the samples on the AMQP lite github page, I have successfully connected using SASL ANONYMOUS then token on $cbs endpoint. (https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/blob/master/docs/articles/service_to_iothub.md)

Generating SAS tokens on every request is redundant and I would like to use the shared access policy and key as user and password when connecting to IoT Hub.
I have followed the documentation at https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/blob/master/docs/articles/building_application.md#specifying-an-address together with the indications on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#protocol-specifics , but i keep getting some unauthenticated error with code "Sys".

Credentials are certainly good as I use them to generate SAS tokens and I've tried variations of the username (with/without domain) with no success. I have specifically checked that username and password are URL encoded.

Following the documentation on SASL standard, the error code Sys seems to indicate some issue on the receiver side (http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-3206.txt page 3).

Has anyone else hit this problem? Is there any solution or it is possible to connect to IoT Hub this way?

Thanks,
George

Comment: > Generating SAS tokens on every request is redundant. Just to point out, you do not have to generate a new SAS token on every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get "amqp:unauthorized-access" error due to without sending put-token message:

```
        string sasToken = GetSharedAccessSignature(null, device_key, resourceUri, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
        bool cbs = PutCbsToken(connection, host, sasToken, audience);
```

I test on Windows 10 desktop with the following code, it works for both sending and receiving:

```
    static string host = "[IOT_HUB_NAME].azure-devices.net";
    static int port = 5671;
    static string device_id = "[DEVICE_ID]";
    static string device_key = "[DEVICE_KEY]";
    static Session session;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Address address = new Address(host, port, null, null);
        Connection connection = new Connection(address);

        string audience = Fx.Format("{0}/devices/{1}", host, device_id);
        string resourceUri = Fx.Format("{0}/devices/{1}", host, device_id);

        string sasToken = GetSharedAccessSignature(null, device_key, resourceUri, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
        bool cbs = PutCbsToken(connection, host, sasToken, audience);

        session = new Session(connection);

        SendEvent();
        ReceiveCommands();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static private void SendEvent()
    {
        string entity = Fx.Format("/devices/{0}/messages/events", device_id);

        SenderLink senderLink = new SenderLink(session, "sender-link", entity);

        var messageValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("i am a message.");
        Message message = new Message()
        {
            BodySection = new Data() { Binary = messageValue }
        };

        senderLink.Send(message);
        senderLink.Close();
    }

    static private void ReceiveCommands()
    {
        string entity = Fx.Format("/devices/{0}/messages/deviceBound", device_id);

        ReceiverLink receiveLink = new ReceiverLink(session, "receive-link", entity);

        Message received = receiveLink.Receive();
        if (received != null)
            receiveLink.Accept(received);
        Console.WriteLine(received.BodySection.ToString());
        receiveLink.Close();
    }
```

For more information you can reference "[CONNECTING TO THE AZURE IOT HUB USING AN AMQP STACK](https://paolopatierno.wordpress.com/2015/10/24/connecting-to-the-azure-iot-hub-using-an-the-amqp-stack/)".

**Update:**

Instead of using SAS token like above code piece, the following code use shared access policy and key(SASL PLAIN):

```
    static string host = "[IOT_HUB_NAME].azure-devices.net";
    static int port = 5671;
    static string device_id = "[DEVICE_ID]";
    static string device_key = "[DEVICE_KEY]";
    private const string username_hublevel = "iothubowner@sas.root.[IOT_HUB_NAME]";
    private const string password_hublevel = "SharedAccessSignature sr={URL-encoded-resourceURI}&sig={signature-string}&se={expiry}&skn={policyName}";

    static Session session;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Address address = new Address(host, port, username_hublevel, password_hublevel);
        Connection connection = new Connection(address);

        string audience = Fx.Format("{0}/devices/{1}", host, device_id);
        string resourceUri = Fx.Format("{0}/devices/{1}", host, device_id);

        session = new Session(connection);

        SendEvent();
        Console.WriteLine("Sent Hello AMQP!");
        ReceiveCommands();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I managed to connect to IoT using SAS token, but I want to do it without the SAS token. I want to use the shared access policy and key as user password when I create the address for the connection, in which case I would use SASL PLAIN.

Comment: @GeorgeOnofrei I add code part of using SASL PLAIN. You can check the  answer. It works for me. If there is any concern please feel free let me know.

Comment: Thanks! Code looks okay and is in the same direction as some indication on github. Here is a reference to a question from there: https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/issues/195